# Why is the Aggregator module not creating a block

Tags: blocks, feeds

I am using the Aggregator module that is part of Drupal 9 core.  I am following the docs on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/aggregator/overview

After I create a feed and update it, I understand that a custom block should automagically be created.  But I cannot find any new blocks under /admin/structure/block.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in my D9 I first chose to insert a block to a location, then looked for aggregation in the list of blocks offered. I'm possibly assuming you did this but you didn't say so. You can't just look under structure > blocks. You must choose to insert block at location then pick the kind of block you want, in this case aggregator feed. There's no decent support on D9 Aggregator and it even appears they may remove it at D10, possibly the feeds module is gaining popularity and better versatility. I also found the "Category" configuration that used to be available in D7/8 is no longer

Answer (score 1):

Once added a feed to the Aggregator module, and once the feed is updated, visiting /admin/structure/block shows *Aggregator feed* as one of the possible blocks.

> [image: screenshot]

Click on the *Place block* button for the region where you want the block to appear. The dialog box that appears will show a list of blocks implemented by modules; one of them is the *Aggregator feed* block. Click on the *Place block* button shown for that block; a new dialog will appear to config the block.

> [image: screenshot]

The *Select the feed that should be displayed* field allows you to select the feed to show in the block, while the *Number of news items in block* field allows to select how many articles will appear in that block.

Once I clicked on the *Save block*, I saw the block in the region I selected.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your advice but unfortunately, I do not see  Aggregator feed listed under /admin/structure/block.  When I search for it there are no results.  This is my problem.  Any advice on how to debug this?

Comment: If you added at least a feed to the Aggregator module's list, I would think there is a module that alters the list of blocks that can be added or that alters the list of feeds. For the list of blocks, it could also be the theme. If it's a module causing the problem, it's enough to uninstall one module at time and verify the Aggregator block is listed. I would also try uninstalling and re-installing the Aggregator module, just in case, and check all the Aggregator module's files are copied on the server.